# How do I extend FOSRestBundle's normalizer to decorate output with data from exception?

Tags: symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle

Right now, when there is an `HttpException` thrown, it gets intercepted, and I get a response with JSON like:

```json
{
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I created a custom base class `ExpandedHttpException`:

```php
class ExpandedHttpException extends HttpException {
    public readonly array $data;
}
```

Now, I'd like to make the response body like this if an exception that extends `ExpandedHttpException` is thrown:

```json
{
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden",
  "data": {...}
}
```

As I discovered, the actual serialization happens within `FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\FlattenExceptionNormalizer::normalize()` but I can neither extend it (it's final) nor replace (it makes use of FOSRest's internal classes).  So, how do I decorate the standard response with extra data?